Calcular el tiempo entre 2 diferentes horas en python
estoy haciendo un sistema de marcas, en el cual tengo que sacar el tiempo entre 2 horas diferentes, por ejemplo 18:36 y 21:56. Tengo un código pero no me funciona, me gustaria saber si me pueden echar una mano a ver si logro hacerlo funcionar, acá se los dejo:
def calcular_diferencia(tiempo_inicio, tiempo_fin):
    formato_hora = "%H:%M"
    t1 = datetime.strptime(str(tiempo_inicio), formato_hora)
    t2 = datetime.strptime((tiempo_fin), formato_hora)
    
    # Calcula la diferencia en minutos
    diferencia = t2 - t1
    total_minutos = diferencia.total_seconds() / 60
    
    minutes_round = total_minutos / 100

    # Redondeo personalizado
    return redondear_a_dos_decimales(minutes_round)

def redondear_a_dos_decimales(valor):
    # Redondea hacia abajo a 2 decimales
    valor_redondeado = math.floor(valor * 100) / 100
    
    # Redondeo adicional si el decimal es mayor a 0.59
    if valor_redondeado % 1 >= 0.59:
        return math.ceil(valor_redondeado)  # Redondea hacia el siguiente entero
    else:
        return valor_redondeado

Ya intenté con ese código pero no funcionó, alguna idea?

No lo mencionas, pero ¿el resultado debe estar en horas o minutos? ¿Cuál debe ser el resultado qué esperas de 18:36 y 21:56? Una consideración importante es cuando un empleado entra en un día y sale en otro, por ejemplo entra a las 18:00 y sale a las 01:00 del siguiente día. Eso te obliga a manejar la fecha completa Y-m-d H:M:S.

Mirá, el problema puede estar en cómo estás redondeando, primero, asegurate de que estás usando bien el strptime para convertir las horas en el formato "%H:%M". Después, calculas la diferencia en minutos y lo redondeas como quieres.
Intenta probar de esta manera:
from datetime import datetime
import math

def calcular_diferencia(tiempo_inicio, tiempo_fin):
    formato_hora = "%H:%M"
    t1 = datetime.strptime(tiempo_inicio, formato_hora)
    t2 = datetime.strptime(tiempo_fin, formato_hora)
    diferencia = t2 - t1
    total_minutos = diferencia.total_seconds() / 60
    return redondear_a_dos_decimales(total_minutos)

def redondear_a_dos_decimales(valor):
    valor_redondeado = math.floor(valor * 100) / 100
    if valor_redondeado % 1 >= 0.59:
        return math.ceil(valor_redondeado)
    else:
        return valor_redondeado

tiempo_inicio = "18:36"
tiempo_fin = "21:56"
resultado = calcular_diferencia(tiempo_inicio, tiempo_fin)
print("Diferencia en minutos:", resultado)

con eso deberia de funcionar
